# A 90s anime/cartoons/ with a main character who has a red mecha suit with a weapon like a spear

Tags: story-identification, robots, anime, mecha

I am searching for an animation with two partners. They travel around the world, and they have robots suits. I remember the suits have some neuronal connections with the pilots. The main character has a red robot suit with a spear or some kind of weapon that can penetrate anything.

It's an old show. I know that I saw it when I was a really young man (around 2001-2002).

I've seen a *lot* of anime with mecha, and yet I didn't find this animation. It's not any of the *Gundam* series. As noted in my response to two of the answers below, it's also not *Neon Genesis Evangelion* or *Tekkaman*.

What I remember: they were riding a car with robots, the main character was sick, his partner was about 50-55 years old, the robot was red, and I remember very well only one phase, an enemy it is not worth remembering if a sword was a spear, but I know it was a symbiosis between the two, the robots were not as big as evangelion and did not fight in space as some of the gundam, I know it has a sharp shape, and it's like if you remember the latest versions of blue genders robots.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include more details as this will make your story more easy to identify. [Check this meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/20199) which can give some guidance on types of information that can be helpful (and may help you remember additional details). For instance, I notice you have given more details in comments to answers, include those details in the question. Which country were you in when you saw this? What language was it in? How did the characters "travel around the world"? (Plane, boat, in their mecha, etc). Who was the enemy?

Comment: look, what I remember: they were riding a car with robots, the main character was sick, his partner was about 50-55 years old, the robot was red, and I remember very well only one phase, an enemy it is not worth remembering if a sword was a spear, but I know it was a symbiosis between the two, the robots were not as big as evangelion and did not fight in space as some of the gundam, I know it has a sharp shape, and it's like if you remember the latest versions of blue genders robots

Comment: Do you remember when you saw this cartoon? You wrote _"when I was a really young man"_, but that's not a precise information! :-)

Comment: 2001-2002
I have been looking for this show for 10 years now

Comment: If you can remember a list of things it's not (over and above the ones already established), that would help - otherwise, you may get five more answers that are things you know it's not already. That might prompt people to think of things they know that aren't on the list. Any other details you can provide are worthwhile; for instance, what channel it was on, and/or the country you watched it in (or, if it wasn't broadcast, the format you watched it in - if on a physical medium (disc or tape) anything you recall about the cover).

Comment: Have you found the anime? I have been looking for the same anime for a while now.

Answer (score 6):

This could be [*"Tekkaman: The Space Knight"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekkaman:_The_Space_Knight) / *"Uchū no Kishi Tekkaman"* (the English wikipedia page does not have a lot of details, the Italian and Spanish ones are quite richer).

First of all, an image:

[image]

**Matching details:**

- (mostly) red mecha suit
- spear-like weapon
- the suits have some neuronal connections with the pilot
- old show: it aired in Japan in 1975, in the US in 1984

**Not-so-matching details:**

- 2 parters: here we have a sentient robot (Pegas, the blue one in the background) and an armored pilot instead

Comment: the action is on Earth and when I said the partners I meant 2 people one was older and the other the main character! i see Tekkaman too!

Comment: I recommend adding Tekkaman Blade as a possibility to this answer - that was my first guess when I saw the question, and it might be the right one. All of the factors that made the original series a likely candidate hold up for Blade as well.

Answer (score 5):

Could this possibly have been *Neon Genesis Evangelion*?

> I remember the suits have some neuronal connections with the pilots.

Assuming you mean "neural", the pilots in Evangelion do indeed have mental connections to their mecha.

> The main character has a red robot suit with a spear or some kind of weapon that can penetrate anything.

She's not *the* main character, but Asuka Langley pilots a red mecha (EVA-02). The protagonists' three mecha all have weapons called Progressive Knives that can cut through almost anything.

[image]

Later in the series, an actual spear called the Spear of Longinus shows up, which has the power to penetrate the "AT Fields" generated by the series' main villains, the Angels.

[image]

*Evangelion* was made in the 90s, so it fits your time frame. What doesn't fit is that there are three mecha pilots, not two. I must confess I haven't actually watched it myself, so I don't know whether the "travel around the world" part matches.

Comment: i see evangelion too soo no.

Comment: I did think you may have seen it, as you said you'd watched a lot of mecha anime, but it was still worth a shot, just in case.

Comment: thank you very much I'll be patient maybe someone knows what I'm looking for. I just know it's the first robot animation I've ever seen and that's exactly what I forgot it